# Importing JS in Angular CLI 1.2.4

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, angular-cli

I am trying to do a cound integration to my existing angular project

https://www.npmjs.com/package/kount-access-api

I Installed the NPM module and obviously it in JS and not TS and so i used the below lines in angular-cli.json

```
 "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/kount-access-api/lib/kount-access-api.js"
      ],
```

However i am  getting below error in console,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>       at eval (eval at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9), :25:14)
>       at eval ()
>       at webpackJsonp.../../../../script-loader/addScript.js.module.exports (addScript.js:9)
>       at Object.../../../../script-loader/index.js!../../../../kount-access-api/lib/kount-access-api.js (kount-access-api.js?9331:1)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap a89535f…:54)
>       at Object.2 (scripts.bundle.js:37)
>       at **webpack_require** (bootstrap a89535f…:54)
>       at webpackJsonpCallback (bootstrap a89535f…:25)
>       at scripts.bundle.js:1

Any pointers is appreciated

Comment: did you try to remove and reinstall `npm_modules`? Seams like it is not a problem with `kount-access-api` itself. `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` that is a problem.

Comment: I don't think it is the problem with Install. It is just that Angular -cli uses webpack internally that doesn't have RequireJS to handle require calls i assume. I dont know how to fix it though.

Comment: I did install the `latest cli` and then installed `kount-access-api` and it works

Comment: @kuncevic can you please share the code because i cant get it to work. I tried removing and adding and also upgrading CLI.

Comment: ahh sorry it is actually didn't work. Check my answer blow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just explored the library you are trying to reference and by checking [its github](https://github.com/Kount/access-api-clients/tree/master/nodejs/kount-access-api) page it is clearly says that it is `nodejs` library. Also I checked the code and it is referencing the [Needle](https://github.com/tomas/needle) which is another `nodejs` library

```
/**
 * Required Libraries
 */
// needle is needed for http calls
var needle = require("needle");
```

Check out `node_modules\kount-access-api\node_modules\.bin\` and you will see what I am talking about. So it won't work in a browser.

I have never used Kount but seams like you have to connect to Kount from server side, not from browser/client side.

Checkout these links:

https://github.com/Kount

http://kount.github.io/

Comment: You are right. That package is meant to run at server side and not on browser. Kount seems to have another component just the data collector  that just runs on browser and picks data.thank you for the help 